# How to fill values by referencing other field values in BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have these 2 tables

parents

| name | address |
| --- | --- |
| a | one |
| b | two |
| c | three |

children

| name | parents |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | a |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | a |
| 5 | c |
| 6 | b |

I'd like to get the result like this,

children_address

| name | address |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one |
| 2 | one |
| 3 | two |
| 4 | one |
| 5 | three |
| 6 | two |

children's address is the same as their parents'.

How can I get this result in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all childrens have parents, I'd use [INNER JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#inner_join) to achieve the desired output:

```
SELECT
  c.name, p.address
FROM
  parents_table AS p
INNER JOIN
  children_table AS c ON p.name = c.parents
ORDER BY 
  c.name
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
name address
---- -------
1    one
2    one
3    two
4    one
5    three
6    two
```

If you use [LEFT JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#left_outer_join), you are probably assuming that not all children have a parent. In case that happens, the result with return null on the address column of the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT children.name, address FROM dataset.children children
LEFT JOIN dataset.parents parents ON parents.name = children.parents
```